# Find residue at an essential singularity

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex

I want to find

```
Residue[(x^3 Exp[1/x])/(1 - x^2), {x, 0}]
```

And when I try to evaluate this I have again:

```
Residue[(E^(1/x) x^3)/(1 - x^2), {x, 0}]
```

So the question is: how to find the residue?

Comment: `Exp[1/x]` has an essential singularity at the origin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not what you are hoping for but is there a pole at x = 0?

```
Limit[(x^3 Exp[1/x])/(1 - x^2), x -> 0]

(* Indeterminate *)
```

I think you have an essential singularity which takes all values `as x -> 0`.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you, it is a good idea to use the definition of residue by "limit".

Comment: I will think about a type of this point, maybe you are right and it is an essential singularity, I am not sure :)

Comment: That is not enough, it can still be a pole. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_singularity You need to check 1/f too. Limit[1/((x^3 Exp[1/x])/(1 - x^2)), x -> 0] (it is also Indeterminate, so indeed essential singularity).

Answer (score 7):

Just because the origin is an essential singularity doesn't mean that the residue does not exist.

The sum of the residues of all of the singularities is 0. Three of the singularities have residues that are easy to compute:

```
f[x_] := (x^3 Exp[1/x])/(1-x^2)
res1minus = Residue[f[x], {x, -1}]
res1 = Residue[f[x], {x, 1}]
res∞ = Residue[f[x], {x, ∞}]
```

> -(1/(2 E))
>
> -(E/2)
>
> 3/2

So, the residue at 0 is simply:

```
res0 = - res1minus - res1 - res∞
```

> -(3/2) + 1/(2 E) + E/2

which has the numerical value:

```
res0 //N
```

> 0.0430806

Let's check this using the definition of residues:

```
r = .5; (* use a radius that only encloses the singularity at 0 *)
1/(2 Pi I) NIntegrate[f[r Exp[I θ]] (r I Exp[I θ]), {θ, 0, 2 π}]
```

> 0.0430806 - 1.35532*10^-14 I

Comment: Integrate instead of NIntegrate gives even a symbolic result.

Comment: Not here, it does not. Integrate does not provide symbolic result. Also to author: 10^-14 I is fake term, that is just a bug in Mathematica.

Comment: In 13.1 it gives 1/2(-3+1/E+E) but you still need to change .5 to 1/2.

Answer (score 0):

You can see that your function has an essentially singularity by plot its amplitude on a small circle around the origin.  For example

```
Module[{x = 0.1 Exp[I θ]}, 
 Plot[Abs[(E^(1/x) x^3)/(1 - x^2)], {θ, 0, 2 π}, 
  PlotRange -> All]]
```