# Possible bug in ResidueSum

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs, complex

Trying a new command of version 13.1 `ResidueSum`, I obtain

```
FunctionMeromorphic[{(x^2 - x + 2)/x, Abs[x] > 5}, x]
```

> `True`

```
ResidueSum[{(x^2 - x + 2)/x, Abs[x] > 5}, x]
```

> `0`

which is in discordance with

```
Residue[(x^2-x+2)/x,{x,ComplexInfinity}]
```

> `-2`

Is the above result of `ResidueSum` incorrect or I don't understand something?

Comment: I'd like to add that `Abs[ComplexInfinity] > 5` performs `True`.

Comment: `FunctionPoles[f[x], x]` indicates that it only considers the pole at `x == 0` which is not in the region `Abs[x] > 5`

Comment: @BobHanlon: Thank you fo your interest to the question. Residues are not necessary connected with poles (see [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_(complex_analysis)) for info).

Comment: The documentation states "ResidueSum computes the sum of residues at all poles of f." That may not be what you want calculated, but that is what it says it is calculating.

Comment: @BobHanlon: `ComplexInfinity` may be considered as a pole of `x^2-x+2)/x`. (see [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeros_and_poles) for info).

Comment: As previously pointed out, Mma only considers the pole at `x == 0`

Comment: @BobHanlon: It should be treated as a bug. Please, submit it to WRI's technical support.

Comment: @BobHanlon: Up to the documentation https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ResidueSum.html. , "
`ResidueSum[{f,cons},z]`
finds the sum of residues of `f` within the solution set of the constraints `cons`.". Don't hesitate to ask for further explanation in need.

Comment: What is wrong in my question? Down-votes do not make Mathematica better  and do not fix bugs.

Comment: I believe the help files should be updated to remove this ambiguity:  ResidueSum states it computes residues of ALL poles of f but pole at infinity is a legitimate pole of f.  And FunctionPoles states it finds a pole at z if function has Laurent series in terms of powers of (x-z).   But there is no Lorent series in terms of $(x-\infty)$; need to first transform function via Residue at infinity and then compute residue at zero.

Comment: @josh: Look in [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series) for info about Laurent series around infinity.

Comment: I have to wonder why it would fall on a responder to submit this as a bug report.

Comment: I think the second bullet item under Details makes clear that this will not consider poles at infinity. Which explains `In[1]:= ResidueSum[x, x]

Out[1]= 0`. (Most people would be concerned if that gave anything other than zero.)

Comment: @DanilLichtblau: Sorry, don't understand your "Most people would be concerned if that gave anything other than zero" in view of `Residue[x,{x,ComplexInfinity}]` which results in `0`.

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau:  Can you be more specific regarding second bullet item?  I do not see anywhere under detals of `FunctionPoles` or `ResidueSum` where it specifically states it does not include poles at infinity.

Comment: @josh It shows a contour integral in C. That of necessity excludes any pole at infinity. This is specific to `ResidueSum` and does not apply to `FunctionPoles` (nor did I claim to the contrary).

Comment: Here is another way to view the behavior. If you want to get a nonzero result when you exclude all poles except at infinity, then what should you get when you include all poles (including at infinity)? That is, how do you avoid getting zero?

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau:: Sorry, your latest comment is off-topic. My question is about  `ResidueSum[{(x^2 - x + 2)/x, Abs[x] > 5}, x]`, not about `ResidueSum[{(x^2 - x + 2)/x,  x]`.  At least, we see a poor documentation to `ResidueSum`. BTW, residues are defined not only at poles. For example, residue of $e^{ \frac 1 z}$ at $z=0$ equals $1$, but `Residue[Exp[1/z],{z,0}]` returns the input.   We again see that Mathematica math differs from traditional math in some fields.

Comment: It is very funny how countourintegration.m external package fails on your specific function (it has residues solver). Very nice work. BTW, are we sure Abs[x] > 5 includes ComplexInfinity? I though that one is just for normal cases, where there are two infinities, but the limits at them are different. https://www.researchgate.net/publication/319881506_Mathematica_Package_ContourIntegration and examples here https://www.researchgate.net/publication/319881038_Mathematica_Notebook_Contour_Integration_P1

Comment: @ВалерийЗаподовников:  Looking in both papers,  I stucked with its initialization "The Mathematica package comprises all definitions, procedures, replacement rules etc. which are required to run the main procedure ContourIntegral etc. .  After successful execution of the package the Mathematica version, date and time are shown" . `Abs[ComplexInfinity]>5` produces `True` as written in my first comment in this thread. Thank you anyway.

Comment: That is just a warning, yes. VersionDateTime is not used for anything though. Just type calculateResidues[(x^2-x+2)/x,x, All, {}, "On"] that will fail with "Part specification False[[1]] is longer than depth of object".

Comment: @ВалерийЗаподовников: Sorry, the package does not work for me (nb file on demand).

Comment: It does work on my 13.1! You need both files, .m file from the first link and do not open it, just open the .nb file and if those are in the same folder "Evaluate Initialisation cells" on nb will be effective, it will print a warning on VersionDateTime, but will return some stuff and it will also give you a new palette. The point here is that it does not work for your function, while it works in many cases Residue[] itself fails!

Comment: Off topic? Hmmm...no, I don't think so. Again, what result do you expect from `ResidueSum[(x^2 - x + 2)/x, x]`? Do you think it should give zero? I will agree the documentation could say more about how poles at infinity are handled. And maybe offer an option for handling them differently.

Comment: Re handling of residues at essential singularities: `In[70]:= Residue[Exp[1/z], {z, 0}]

Out[70]= Residue[E^(1/z), {z, 0}]`. So not perfect, but better than a wrong result.

Comment: Yes this was the one "while it works in many cases Residue[] itself fails" I mentioned above and author codified the fix. But we know that, see (BTW, FunctionMeromorphic is also false for both) https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/208877/find-residue-at-an-essential-singularity So anyway, I think ResidueSum is just not counting any Residues for a pole at ComplexInfinity (all polinomials, BTW) or residues for zero at c. infinity or for essential singularity at c. infinity. Branch point do not have a residue at least. :) With that package even branch points are an easy cake though.

Comment: Abs[ComplexInfinity] is just normal Infinity. ComplexInfinity > 5 fails. ComplexInfinity is not more than 5, it is more AND less than 5. Riemann sphere is not a projective plane.