# Calculate residues or Laurent series in essential singuliarites

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex, singularity

I noticed that for example $\sin(1/x)$ wolfram alpha is unable to calculate the residue at $x=0$ or the laurent expansion around $x=0$. Even though in this example it is not too hard to do it by hand, I wonder why wolfram alpha just outputs "no poles found" for residues and "no series expansion available" in the second case, even though they obviously exist?

Edit: It does not work in Mathematica too, there my output is just my input

Residue[Sin[1/z], {z, 0}]

Therefore I wonder why that is so and if there is any other way to get the wanted result?

Comment: I'm afraid [questions about *Wolfram Alpha* are off-topic here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic#:~:text=Some%20kinds%20of,on%20Wolfram%20Alpha). You could [edit] your question and provide *Wolfram Language* code of the problem you are working on to make it on-topic.

Comment: I tried the same in mathematica but there it does not work either, even though the output is different from wolfram alphas.

Comment: [See here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/208877) for a related question.

Comment: Try adding a small positive or negative constant to the denominator under the sine and try to arrange it in a series at the zero point. Analyze the behavior of the coefficients of the terms of the series. For example: `e=0.001` `Series[Sin[1/(x + e)], {x, 0, 3}]`

Answer (score 0):

Making use of [the definition of the residue](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Residue_of_an_analytic_function) of $f(z)$ at $z=a$ as the value of the integral $$\frac 1 {2\pi i}\int_\gamma f(z)\,dz, $$ where $\gamma$ is a circle centered at $a$ of  a small radius $r$, one obtains

```
Integrate[I*r*Exp[I*t]*Sin[1/z] /. z -> r*Exp[I*t], {t, 0, 2*Pi}, 
Assumptions -> r > 0 && r < 1]/(2*Pi*I)
```

> `1`